# What is the significance of "{" "}" braces around this react library code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I was going through react library code. After going through I found a special piece of code I am unable to understand its significance. Can someone help?

```
var validateFormat = function () {};

{
  validateFormat = function (format) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  };
}
```

Here why react developer has wrapped the validateFormat into curly braces? is there any significance of doing this.

If I do the following it works the same -

```
var validateFormat = function () {};

validateFormat = function (format) {
   if (format === undefined) {
   throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
   }
};
```

Comment: Can you cite this source? They seem superfluous, but my guess is you've "dumbed down the code" for the sake of presentation and just making them _appear_ superfluous.

Comment: It creates a block around the function. But since there's no block scope when using vars, it has no meaning written this way. Possible explanations that come to mind are: 1) Transpiled code, 2) Inexperienced dev, 3) There used to be a label on the block that got removed.

Comment: @Shilly `since there's no block scope in JS` is wrong. Starting in ES6 `let` and `const` are block scope declarations.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, yeah but this example uses var, if you really think what I typed is confusing, I'll edit it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I copied this from the react library code itself. Just look at the development version of react. You'll find it there

Comment: @abhishekgangwar there's like 100s of files in [here](https://github.com/facebook/react). Save us some time and [edit] your question to properly cite this source.

Comment: @JohnKennedy [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53942100/5267751) are saying exactly that.  Why comment?

Comment: The question is actually off-topic because it's caused by incorrectly pasted code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The block scope is a result of their [babel-preset-fbjs](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-fbjs). If you look at the [*original source*](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/shared/invariant.js#L20-L28) you'll find that instead, this function is conditionally defined depending on the value of `__DEV__`, which is optimized out during transpilation since it is equivalent to [`process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-fbjs/plugins/dev-expression.js#L37).

```
let validateFormat = () => {};

if (__DEV__) {
  validateFormat = function(format) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that the code was misquoted.

Answer (score 3):

This code makes perfect sense.

```
var v = function () {};

{
  v = function (format) {
    // actual code
  };
}
```

The first assignment defines `v` to an empty placeholder function so that code does not break.

The second assignment contains the *actual code* of the function. It is inside a *block scope*, which is a legit JS construct.

But... block scoping *does nothing* because of variable hoisting, which nullifies any locality contrary to C/C++ adepts' expectations. Many say there is no block scoping in JS, which is false. There is block scoping but it's ineffective (apart from more recent `let`/`const` declarations).

So what this code does is abuse the *ineffective* block syntax to separate visually parts of code.

But (and this is what I think is going on here) what we see here is just an *EXAMPLE*. I could very well come up with another example that makes perfect sense, such as this:

```
var v = function () {};

{
  let localValue = 0;

  v = function (format) {
    // actual code using localValue
    localValue = 1;
  };
}
```

In other words, you may find other examples in the code base which leverages block scoping through `let`/`const` and encapsulates the definition as shown. The example you give just doesn't leverage this opportunity but the scoping remains because:

- it does not disrupt or break code;
- uniformity;
- in future may carry more weight adding `let`/`const`.

This is all guessing on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces here are [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). They don't serve any good purpose in this case and can safely omitted. [Block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#Block_Scoping_Rules) doesn't work with `var`. Even if it was `let`, block statement wouldn't affect it because `validateFormat` is already defined outside block statement.

An example where block statement is useful would be:

```
let validateFormat = function () {};

{
  // doesn't reassign validateFormat from outer scope
  let validateFormat = function (format) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  };
  // validateFormat from block scope is used here
}

// validateFormat from outer scope is used here
```

**The answer provides technically correct explanation. The real problem here is that the question contains wrong code that doesn't make sense because `if (...)` statement was omitted when the code was pasted, as accepted answer shows.**