# Why do people write js like this？

Tags: javascript

```
  var type = (0, _reactIs.isMemo)(nodeOrComponent) ? nodeOrComponent.type.type : nodeOrComponent.type;
```

`(0, _reactIs.isMemo)` really confuse me. What's the meaning of this?

ps: I know `(0, _reactIs.isMemo)` this expression's value is `_reactIs.isMemo`

Comment: perhaps this is the result of some "transpiler" (e.g. babeljs) or "bundler" (e.g. webpack) process - so nobody has actually written this garbage, but some process has produced this valid, yet garbage, code

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53941926/1541563)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275135/why-does-babel-rewrite-imported-function-call-to-0-fn

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comma operator there ensures that what's inside the parentheses is evaluated as an expression without a calling context.

To take a shorter example, if the code was:

```
var type = obj.fn(someArg);
```

then `fn` would be called with a calling context of `obj`. But the original *untranspiled* code, whatever it is, does not have such a calling context, so in order to be faithful to the original code, the calling context has to be removed, which can be done with the comma operator:

```
var type = (0, obj.fn)(someArg);
```

Another way of doing the same thing would be:

```
var fn = obj.fn;
var type = fn(someArg);
```

(but that takes more characters, so minifiers prefer the comma operator version)

This is a silly-looking minification trick that's often seen with imported modules. Usually, you'd only be looking at the *source* code, which won't have this sillyness.